# Create a drupal 6 views slideshow from a single content type that has both, image and video fields

Tags: 6, media, views

I need a little direction. I've created a content type that has both, images and videos attached to a node. I need to create a single frame slideshow that riffles through the mixed media. Currently, I'm using the Embedded Media Field as well as the ImageField to upload the content. I'd like to keep that within the same content type if possible. For the most part, the slideshow is working, yet it displays both fields together.  I want a single slide per media type.  I've excluded one type, but adding the field programmatically has been a little challenging.

Answer (score 0):

The only way I've been able to somewhat achieve this is by creating individual nodes for the video and image content.  I then use views to filter for both types. Clumsy for the content editor, but I guess it works.